# How can I continue URLSession dataTaskPublisher or another Publisher after error?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have an app that needs to check a status on a server:

- every 30 seconds
- whenever the app enters the foreground

I'm doing this by merging two publishers, then calling `flatMap` the merged publisher's output to trigger the API request.

I have a function that makes an API request and returns a publisher of the result, also including logic to check the response and throw an error depending on its contents.

It seems that once a `StatusError.statusUnavailable` error is thrown, the `statusSubject` stops getting updates. How can I change this behavior so the `statusSubject` continues getting updates after the error? I want the API requests to continue every 30 seconds and when the app is opened, even after there is an error.

I also have a few other points where I'm confused about my current code, indicated by comments, so I'd appreciate any help, explanation, or ideas in those areas too.

Here's my example code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct StatusResponse: Codable {
    var response: String?
    var error: String?
}

enum StatusError: Error {
    case statusUnavailable
}

class Requester {

    let statusSubject = CurrentValueSubject<StatusResponse,Error>(StatusResponse(response: nil, error: nil))

    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {
        // Check for updated status every 30 seconds
        let timer = Timer
            .publish(every: 30,
                      tolerance: 10,
                      on: .main,
                      in: .common,
                      options: nil)
            .autoconnect()
            .map { _ in true } // how else should I do this to be able to get these two publisher outputs to match so I can merge them?

        // also check status on server when the app comes to the foreground
        let foreground = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)
            .map { _ in true }

        // bring the two publishes together
        let timerForegroundCombo = timer.merge(with: foreground)

        timerForegroundCombo
            // I don't understand why this next line is necessary, but the compiler gives an error if I don't have it
            .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
            .flatMap { _ in self.apiRequest() }
            .subscribe(statusSubject)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    private func apiRequest() -> AnyPublisher<StatusResponse, Error> {
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/status-endpoint")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: StatusResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .tryMap({ status in
                if let error = status.error,
                    error.contains("status unavailable") {
                    throw StatusError.statusUnavailable
                } else {
                    return status
                }
            })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the error? Do you actually show it to the user, or do you just want to discard it?

Comment: I want to update the UI based on a subscriber to the subject rather than discarding it, and continue retrying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publishing a failure always ends a subscription. Since you want to continue publishing after an error, you **cannot** publish your error as a failure. You must instead change your publisher's output type. The standard library provides `Result`, and that's what you should use.

```
func makeStatusPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Result<StatusResponse, Error>, Never> {
    let timer = Timer
        .publish(every: 30, tolerance: 10, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .map { _ in true } // This is the correct way to merge with the notification publisher.

    let notes = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)
        .map { _ in true }

    return timer.merge(with: notes)
        .flatMap({ _ in
            statusResponsePublisher()
                .map { Result.success($0) }
                .catch { Just(Result.failure($0)) }
        })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

This publisher emits either `.success(response)` or `.failure(error)` periodically, and never completes with a failure.

However, you should ask yourself, what happens if the user switches apps repeatedly? Or what if the API request takes more that 30 seconds to complete? (Or both?) You'll get multiple requests running simultaneously, and the responses will be handled in the order they arrive, which might not be the order in which the requests were sent.

One way to fix this would be to use `flatMap(maxPublisher: .max(1)) { ... }`, which makes `flatMap` ignore timer and notification signals while it's got a request outstanding. But it would perhaps be even better for it to start a new request on each signal, and cancel the prior request. Change `flatMap` to `map` followed by `switchToLatest` for that behavior:

```
func makeStatusPublisher2() -> AnyPublisher<Result<StatusResponse, Error>, Never> {
    let timer = Timer
        .publish(every: 30, tolerance: 10, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .map { _ in true } // This is the correct way to merge with the notification publisher.

    let notes = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)
        .map { _ in true }

    return timer.merge(with: notes)
        .map({ _ in
            statusResponsePublisher()
                .map { Result<StatusResponse, Error>.success($0) }
                .catch { Just(Result<StatusResponse, Error>.failure($0)) }
        })
        .switchToLatest()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: If statusResponsePublisher will emit completed event it will cancel whole process, correct? How would you solve that?

Comment: No, it will not cancel the whole process, because `switchToLatest` will wait for the next publisher to arrive from upstream (from the `map`).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it seems if `statusResponsePublisher` will emit `completed` event it will be passed downstream to `switchToLatest` and eventually cancel whole subscription. Even if next publisher will emit something it won't be consumed.

Comment: It sounds like you need to post your own question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use retry() to get this kind of behaviour or catch it...more info here: 
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/combine-error-handling/

Comment: Using retry requires I provide a number of times to retry. I want to retry indefinitely.

Comment: i assumed you would answer this....this is why i added the "or catch it" ..!

Comment: Could you add an example of what you mean by that  in your answer?

Comment: did you click on the link !? there is. an example....and with a big number in retry you could solve it (i know it is not perfect, but it IS a solution)

Comment: @Chris Please check the “Provide context for links” section of [“How do I write a good answer?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Anyway, `retry` won't solve the problem. OP wants to surface the errors to the user, but `retry` discards the errors.